# Can i use if condition on laravel database query?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Can i use `if` condition inside query, I want to use filter when `$request->review = 7` it will show 7 days data and else condition default 30 days data .

```
$reviews = Review::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->orWhere('created_at', '>=', if($request->review == "7"){ $month = 7 })
    ->where('listing_id', $id)
    ->where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)
    ->paginate(6, ['*'], 'review');
```

Comment: ```created_at >= 7``` doesn't seem correct. Is @MarcinNabiałek 's take on the ```created_at``` correct, and you mean "in the last 7 days" and "in the last 30 days"?

Comment: My current query is this
        $reviews = Review::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->orWhere('created_at','>=',$month)->where('listing_id', $id)->where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)->paginate(6, ['*'], 'review');

which is showing last 30 days data and now i want to show 7 days data when some on click on week

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
$reviews = Review::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->orWhere('created_at','>=',now()->subDays($request->review == 7 ? 7 : 30)
    ->where('listing_id', $id)
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->paginate(6, ['*'], 'review');
```

but keep in mind you might still get wrong results.

You should make sure brackets are added into query in correct place, otherwise you might get other user's results, so it's quite possible in fact you would like to use something like this:

```
$reviews = Review::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->where(function($q) use ($request) {
      $q->where('listing_id', $id)
         ->orWhere('created_at','>=',now()->subDays($request->review == 7 ? 7 : 30)
    })
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->paginate(6, ['*'], 'review');
```

but you haven't explained what exact results you want to get from database so it's just a hint.

Comment: not working i have put brackets on correct place
        $reviews = Review::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->orWhere('created_at','>=',now()->subDays($request->review == 7 ? 7: 30))->where('listing_id', $id)->where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)->paginate(6, ['*'], 'review');

Comment: @SandipJha Sorry, but "not working" says nothing. If you don't have any results or the query is completely wrong then you won't get expected results

Answer (score 0):

You can split Eloquent Builder by cursor.

```php
$cursor = Review::orderByDesc('created_at');

if ($request->review == "7") {
    $cursor->orWhere('created_at','>=', 7));
}
$reviews = $cursor->where('listing_id', $id)
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->paginate(6, ['*'], 'review');
```

Comment: when i use this zero result

Answer (score 0):

```
$reviews = Review::where('listing_id', $id)
                 ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);

if($request->review == 7){
    $reviews->Where('created_at','>=',now()->subDays($request->review));
}

if($request->review != 7){
    $reviews->Where('created_at','>=',now()->subDays(30));
}

$reviews->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->paginate(6, ['*'], 'review');
```

After understanding the above, you can go ahead to simplify the above using the ternary operator as you have below.

```
$reviews = Review::where('listing_id', $id)
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
    ->Where('created_at','>=',now()->subDays(($request->review == 7)? 7 : 30));
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(6, ['*'], 'review');
```

Answer (score 0):

$reviews = Review::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');

if ($request->review == "7") {

```
$reviews->orWhere('created_at','>=', 7));
```

}
   $reviews = $reviews->where('listing_id', $id)

```
->where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)

->paginate(6, ['*'], 'review');
```

Comment: $reviews = Review::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
if ($request->review == "7") {
    $reviews->orWhere('created_at','>=', 7));
}
   $reviews = $reviews->where('listing_id', $id)
    ->where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)
    ->paginate(6, ['*'], 'review');